# how to clear all css styles

Tags: html, css, widget

I'm creating a snippet of HTML to allow others to add functionality to their web sites (it is a voting widget).  I've created a snippet of HTML like this:

```
<div>
   [implementation of my voting widget]
</div>
```

I spent a lot of time to get the formatting of this widget just right.  It works great in a sample web page that does not import a style sheet.

When I add the widget to a page on a Drupal site, however, the imported CSS wreaks havoc with my careful formatting.  I'd like my HTML snippet to ignore all CSS style sheets.  Is this possible?

Regardless of whether it is possible, is there a better solution?

Comment: How are you formatting your widget currently without CSS?

Comment: @Alastair Pitts: He is.  He just doesn't want the CSS styles from the page being inherited by his widget.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of relying on your CSS styles not being overridden by any imported stylesheets, you should give your widget a unique id and make sure all of your styles are a derivative of that id making sure to implement any styles you don't want to be overriden (`margin`, `padding`, etc):

```
<div id="votify">
   [implementation of my voting widget]
</div>

#votify {}
#votify ul {}
#votify div span {}
/* etc */
```

Comment: yep, this is how jQuery UI does it (although they use a specific class naming structure)

Comment: he wants the second-party user to be able to drop in his widget, with inline style, without having to mess with their stylesheets. So he wants to somehow clear out all the non-native style for everything within a given `div`.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a reset stylesheet:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Of course, you don't want to overwrite the page's CSS but you can get an idea on how to reset the styles your widget uses and use your personal CSS. So something like...

```
#voting-widget * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: My widget can't interfere with existing layout so I don't think I can import a stylesheet.  Doing that inline would be very ugly.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you import a stylesheet... I'm suggesting you use the ideas presented in that article on resetting styles so that you can make clear for your widget.

Answer (score 2):

Without using a style sheet I think you'd have to explicitly set all margins, padding, fonts, etc in the style attribute so it takes precedence over any CSS sheets that there are.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your widget CSS to default values, and THEN add your formatting code. This will clear out any page styles so you can work from a clean slate.

```
div#widget, div#widget * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  /* ... whatever other reset code ... */

  /* ... then add your own code ... */
  color: red;
}
```